# removing all keys from an array php

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to remove the keys in an array, and just get a plain array.

```
array:2 [▼
   0 => 29
   1 => 27 
]
```

Like change the code above to:

```
array:2 [29, 27]
```

So removing the keys from the array, while only keeping the values.

Comment: `array_values`..? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: That changes nothing to the array, it's still 0 => 29, 0 => 27

Comment: Yeah that's how arrays work in PHP.. It would be kind of hard to access array elements if they weren't indexed.

Comment: The `0=>"1"` means that 1 is accessed by using a the key `0` (ie: index 0). So if you remove it then you won't be able to access your array elements... Do you want to print your array to look like this?

Comment: You can't. A PHP array always has keys. What do you need it for?

Comment: Arrays are self indexed starting from 0 and increments afterwards if you do not assign any special 'key' to the elements in the array.

For example: if you have an array:

$array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
and if you print_r($array); you will get the output:
Array
    (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    ) 
That is how arrays work.

Comment: without a key how can you call it as array, how will you retrieve array values

Comment: Is the question how to output the array without the key or do you literally what to change the array (something that is impossible).

Comment: If you want to echo only the value, just do `foreach ($array as $value) { echo $value; }`, but as other says you can't remove key from a php array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to print the array so that it doesn't include the `keys` you can use this function:

```
function toPlainArray($arr) {
    $output = "[";
    foreach($arr as $val) {
        $output .= $val .", ";
    }
    return substr($output, 0, -2) . "]";
}
```

Usage would be

`echo toPlainArray($arrayName);`

The function goes through each value and appends it to the output string, thus formatting it so that it looks like an array, but is really a string.